# Ionic Google Maps Not working in Android Device but works fine in Browser

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have integrated **google maps** in my app which works fine in the browser.

I have also installed **cordova whitelist** plugin and included the meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 

script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; 

style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

But nothing seems to work.

Please tell me what else should I do to get maps working on my android device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding https:// to the google API url i.e.

from

```
 <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my key]"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my key]"></script>
```